# Help me identify this smd component marked. GMCAA

Tags: identification, surface-mount

This smd is in the power supply section of a small monitor. Size of ic   8 pin  5 x 3.5 mm.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: needs a scale so that we know how large it is. But honestly, you're trying to repair something where probably more things than just this failed. I'm guessing the larger component North of your GMCAA is an SMD inductor, and a large one at that. That suggests there's probably a failed MOSFET nearby, too, and the reason that failed was some overcurrent, which might also mean that a cascade of other things failed.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. My first question was I need to know wot is that component marked with GMCAA if I could find the data sheet of it , to start working on the repair. that smd is definite burnt out.  After I will start looking to the surrounding components. That component is in the power supply area ,and the supply voltage of the board is 12Volts DC. The whole board is a 10 inch colour monitor.